# pylearn2 PATH variable

Tags: python, macos, variables, path, environment

there is surprisingly little documentation or tutorials about this.

I want to run pylearn2 on my Mac OSX 10.11.1.

Acoording to [the tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/tutorial/) I should run at first this line:

```
cd pylearn/pylearn2/scripts/tutorials/grbm_smd/
python make_dataset.py
```

Yet the script fails with this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/python/pylearn2/pylearn2/utils/string_utils.py", line 53, in preprocess
    else os.environ[varname])
  File "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 633, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PYLEARN2_DATA_PATH'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_dataset.py", line 27, in <module>
    train = cifar10.CIFAR10(which_set="train")
  File "/Users/username/python/pylearn2/pylearn2/datasets/cifar10.py", line 71, in __init__
    string_utils.preprocess('${PYLEARN2_DATA_PATH}'),
  File "/Users/username/python/pylearn2/pylearn2/utils/string_utils.py", line 56, in preprocess
    reraise_as(NoDataPathError())
  File "/Users/username/python/pylearn2/pylearn2/utils/exc.py", line 90, in reraise_as
    six.reraise(type(new_exc), new_exc, orig_exc_traceback)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/compat/six.py", line 321, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/username/python/pylearn2/pylearn2/utils/string_utils.py", line 53, in preprocess
    else os.environ[varname])
  File "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 633, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
pylearn2.utils.exc.NoDataPathError: You need to define your PYLEARN2_DATA_PATH environment variable. If you are
using a computer at LISA, this should be set to /data/lisa/data.

Platform-specific instructions for setting environment variables:

Linux
=====
On most linux setups, you can define your environment variable by adding this
line to your ~/.bashrc file:

export PYLEARN2_VIEWER_COMMAND="eog --new-instance"

*** YOU MUST INCLUDE THE WORD "export". DO NOT JUST ASSIGN TO THE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE ***
If you do not include the word "export", the environment variable will be set
in your bash shell, but will not be visible to processes that you launch from
it, like the python interpreter.

Don't forget that changes from your .bashrc file won't apply until you run

source ~/.bashrc

or open a new terminal window. If you're seeing this from an ipython notebook
you'll need to restart the ipython notebook, or maybe modify os.environ from
an ipython cell.

Mac OS X
========

Environment variables on Mac OS X work the same as in Linux, except you should
modify and run the "source" command on ~/.profile rather than ~/.bashrc.


Original exception:
    KeyError: PYLEARN2_DATA_PATH
```

I inserted the following information from the exception into ~/.profile

```
export PYLEARN2_VIEWER_COMMAND="eog --new-instance"
```

and ran

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

As it still threw an exception I did some research and found out I must put the .profile file into the .bash_profile. So I added this line to .bash_profile:

```
#.profile
source ~/.profile
```

However the outcome is still the same :(

**Additional information**

According to the [installation guide](http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/#download-and-installation) says I should add another information to the path envoirement, yet I cannot understand which in particular.

**hidden files in my system**

- .bash_history
- .bash_profile
- .bash_profile-anaconda.bak
- .bash_sessions
- .config
- .ipython
- .local
- .profile
- .python_history
- .theano
- .vminfo

Answer (score 1):

After going through the code myself I've found the solution. There is a bug in the sourcecode, which is missing the download_cifar10.sh script. Plus the tutorial is missing a PATH variable which is necessary.

**Instruction**

1.) set the PATH variable

```
export PYLEARN2_VIEWER_COMMAND="eog --new-instance"
export PYLEARN2_DATA_PATH=/YOURPATHTOHERE/pylearn2/datasets
```

2.) [download cifar-10 (python version)](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html)

3.) unpack it

You will get a "cifar-10-batches-py" folder

4.) Wrap "cifar-10-batches-py" in a "cifar-10" folder

5.) Put the "cifar-10" folder into /pylearn2/datasets

The final path containing the cifar-10 files should be:

```
../pylearn2/datasets/cifar-10-batches-py/cifar-10
```

You're ready to go!

Answer (score 0):

The download script exist:

https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/blob/master/pylearn2/scripts/datasets/download_cifar10.sh

Did you download Pylearn2 correctly? Did you delete files in it by mistake?

Comment: You are right. I downloaded it with the "git clone" command. I dunno why but I really dont have it. However it doesnt matter anymore, as pylearn2 is stopped in development since google announced to opensource tensorflow. The original authors of pylearn switched to googles project.